# TikZ coordinate transformation resulting in miscalculated node position

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Why does the coordinate transformation in the following example result in a miscalculated position for `E`?

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5in, y=0.5in]%% <-- calculation of "E" is incorrect
%%\begin{tikzpicture}%% <-- calculation of "E" is correct

  \coordinate (Q) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A) at (-170:1);
  \coordinate (B) at (-70:1);
  \coordinate (C) at (-20:1);
  \coordinate (D) at (50:1);

  \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,D) 
  \tkzGetPoint{E}

  \draw (A) --  (C);
  \draw (B) --  (D);

  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]  at (E) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the author of `tkz-euclide` assumes the unit vectors will each be `1cm`. You can see what is happening by looking at the definition of `\tkz@InterLL` (a private macro used by `\tkzInterLL` which returns the intersection point which is stored into `coordinate` `E` by `\tkzGetPoint{E}`... phew!).

Here it is:

```
\def\tkz@InterLL(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5{%
%\path (intersection of #1--#2 and #3--#4) coordinate(#5);%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}} 
\tkz@ax\pgf@x %
\tkz@ay\pgf@y %
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}} 
\tkz@bx\pgf@x %
\tkz@by\pgf@y %
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}} 
\tkz@cx\pgf@x %
\tkz@cy\pgf@y %
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}} 
\tkz@dx\pgf@x %
\tkz@dy\pgf@y %
\FPeval\tkz@deltax{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@ax}-\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@bx}}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltax{\tkz@deltax}{28.45274}
\FPeval\tkz@deltaxx{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@cx}-\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@dx}}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltaxx{\tkz@deltaxx}{28.45274}
\FPeval\tkz@deltay{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@ay}-\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@by}}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltay{\tkz@deltay}{28.45274}
\FPeval\tkz@deltayy{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@cy}-\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@dy}}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltayy{\tkz@deltayy}{28.45274}
\FPeval\tkz@deltaxy{(\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@ax}*\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@by})-(\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@ay}*\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@bx})}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltaxy{\tkz@deltaxy}{28.45274}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltaxy{\tkz@deltaxy}{28.45274}
\FPeval\tkz@deltaxxyy{(\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@cx}*\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@dy})-(\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@cy}*\pgf@sys@tonumber{\tkz@dx})}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltaxxyy{\tkz@deltaxxyy}{28.45274}
\FPdiv\tkz@deltaxxyy{\tkz@deltaxxyy}{28.45274}
\FPeval\tkz@div{(\tkz@deltax*\tkz@deltayy)-(\tkz@deltay*\tkz@deltaxx)}
\FPeval\tkz@numx{(\tkz@deltaxy*\tkz@deltaxx)-(\tkz@deltax*\tkz@deltaxxyy)}
\FPeval\tkz@numy{(\tkz@deltaxy*\tkz@deltayy)-(\tkz@deltay*\tkz@deltaxxyy)}
\FPdiv\tkz@xs{\tkz@numx}{\tkz@div}
\FPdiv\tkz@ys{\tkz@numy}{\tkz@div}
\FPround\tkz@xs{\tkz@xs}{5}
\FPround\tkz@ys{\tkz@ys}{5}
\path[coordinate](\tkz@xs,\tkz@ys) coordinate (#5);
}
```

See all those `28.45274`s in the middle? That's converting from an assumed unit vector length of `1cm` into units of `pt` for later rounding and usage.

So, as a test, let's try defining the scale in terms of `in` to be equivalent to `1cm`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3937in, y=0.3937in] % works
%\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3937in, y=1cm]      % works
%\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=0.3937in]      % works
%\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]           % works
%\begin{tikzpicture}                         % works

  \coordinate (Q) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A) at (-170:1);
  \coordinate (B) at (-70:1);
  \coordinate (C) at (-20:1);
  \coordinate (D) at (50:1);

  \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,D) 
  \tkzGetPoint{E}

  \draw (A) --  (C);
  \draw (B) --  (D);

  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]  at (E) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Each one of those lines gives the correct result. But if I do `x=0.5in` or `y=2cm`, the point will be misaligned on one of the axes. And if both unit vectors are changed, the point will be misaligned on both axes.

**TL;DR** When using `tkz-euclide`, you can use any unit vectors you want, as long as they're equivalent to `x=1cm, y=1cm`.

Comment: It seems kind of pointless to rescale the unit vectors if all you're going to do is rescale them equivalently to `1cm`.  ;)

Comment: I appreciate the explanation.  This seems like it should be reported as a bug (at least in my book).

Comment: @A.Ellett I agree, on both counts. `;-)` I sent an email to Alain pointing him to this question. I didn't see any bug reporting links on his website.

Comment: @A.Ellett Not a bug for me, I wanted to use only the same unit vectors. The bug is perhaps in the documentation because this is not described. Thanks to P Gessler for the remark.